# How to access LAN of another router connected via WAN port?

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

I have 2 routers connected via WAN-LAN. Base router that have internet connectivity and another is used to extend network. Both networks are working fine. For some reasons I need to access few devices that are connected to Router 1 with a computer connected to Router 2.

[image: Image showing sample connection diagram]

As per the image I want to access Data Server via Computers directly, like I share drive/folder over LAN.

Comment: are these enterprise routers, or consumer-grade home/SOHO routers? is there a reason you **want** have two networks, or is it just that you need a device to extend cabling or add extra ports? this would certainly be easier if they were both on the same LAN.

Comment: Both routers are consumer-grade home routers. I want to create 2 separate networks and dont want all the devices to communicate with each other. Only few devices that I select should be able to communicate.

Comment: then your best bet is to forward the ports you need through router2, and use the firewall on the server to block traffic originating from disallowed machines in LAN1. See the issue here isn't the firewalling, but the NAT, so forwarding the ports is the only way to make services on DataServer available to LAN1, while maintaining two networks, and  not making DataServer available to only selected hosts. if you had enterprise routers it would be different, but most consumer grade routers won't disable the NAT unless you put it in bridged mode, and have only the one larger network.

Comment: Is there a reason you've connected the LAN to router 2's WAN port? That makes things unnecessarily complicated and typical small routers are not designed to handle this configuration well.

Comment: @FrankThomas So? The computer I'm using right now has only one connection, to a LAN that provides its Internet uplink. A device's Internet uplink can be through a WAN or a LAN link. In this case, it's through a LAN link. So it's puzzling that it was connected to the WAN port.

Comment: @FrankThomas I see the OP indicating the opposite, "Base router that have internet connectivity and *another is used to extend network*." And the whole rest of his question suggests that they don't want to have two discrete networks and that's what's giving them problems.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I'm Just reacting to comment #2. I'll see my way out now.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way of achieving this is by adding routes on the network layer.
For that you would do the following:

1. Ensure both LAN areas are not overlapping
2. Install a route in router 1 that essentially tells it which subnet to reach via which link using which gateway. For the subnet, you'd use the subnet of the LAN connected to router 2, for the gateway you need to specify router 2 and the link is the lan port.
3. Repeat step (2) for router 2.

Now, if you send a packet to the data server from computer 1 the following happens:

1. Assuming there are no routes on computer 1, computer 1 will send the packet using the IP address of the data server and the MAC address of router 1.
2. Router 1 will look at the IP address and check it's routing table. It will see a specific route for the subnet of the data servers IP and hence forward the packet.
3. The new packet carries the MAC address of router 2 and the IP address of the data server. The packet will be placed on the LAN port of the router 1.
4. Router 2 receives the packet and will see that it is destined for the data server. Since that subnet is directly connected it will forward it into the LAN using the MAC address and IP address of the data server.
5. The data server receives the packet and will respond. From there, the same procedure happens again in the opposite direction. It is for that reason that it is vital to make sure that both routers have a route (ie step (2) and (3)). Otherwise the packet is not forwarded on its way back.